# Is it possible to use multiple MockMvc requests in a single test method?

Tags: java, spring, testing, mockmvc

I am studying an old MOOC web development course (as this is an old one, I don't get any credits from it but I do it anyway to learn something new so I don't think it is "cheating"). I have tried to google info about this but so far no luck.

I am using Spring framework and I have to write some tests using MockMvc. This has worked pretty well, but one test has to have one post request to create a new item in a database and one get request to make sure that the new item can be found from the database.

Post request seems to work just fine, I have tested it with another test method and at least it doesn't give an error when I run it with this new test method. I also don't get an error just by making the get request. But when I run the requests one after the other, I get an error:

> Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 19.304 s <<< FAILURE! - in airports.AircraftControllerTest
> testRedirect(airports.AircraftControllerTest)  Time elapsed: 1.678 s  <<< ERROR!
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "aircraft.airport" (template: "aircrafts" - line 26, col 22)
> at airports.AircraftControllerTest.testRedirect(AircraftControllerTest.java:87)

My test class is (I have omitted couple of tests that work as far as I know):

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class AircraftControllerTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private AircraftRepository aircraftRepository;

    public AircraftControllerTest() {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        this.aircraftRepository.deleteAll();
    }
       
    @Test
    public void testRedirect() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(post("/aircrafts").param("name", "XP-55"))
                .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection());
        
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/aircrafts")).andReturn();
               
    }
}
```

So, in the testRedirect() test method I make the post request and after that I make the get request but now I am not at all sure that MockMvc works that way. All examples I have seen make only one request.

As the last point, I have to add more functionality after the get request to find out if that XP-55 can be found from aircraftRepository but I should be able to that.

Any and all help will be useful. Thanks in advance.